# JSON list of primitive values to RESTeasy webservice.

Tags: json, resteasy

I have some REST webservice method defined as this:

```
@GET
@POST
@Path("/blabla")
@Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Wrapped
List<SomeDto> getSomething(
@QueryParam("destination") Long destId,
@QueryParam("parentsIds") List<Long> parents);
```

and when I try to submit JSON data as:

```
urlData: { destination: targetId, parentsIds: [selectedParentId, 31445] },
```

I get an exception

```
Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("parentsIds") value is '31404,31445' for public abstract java.util.List
```

How can I pass list of primitives via JSON to RESTeasy webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass them as separate parameters in the URL.

e.g.

```
  <server>/restendpoint?parentId=1&parentId=2
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/